# Slide in link on hover over

Tags: javascript, hover, transition

I want to create the following action:

When you move your mouse over a piece of text in a navigation bar fixed on the left hand side of the screen, a second piece of text (or an image if that is easier), will appear by sliding out from the left of the page. The second text or image would rest under the first (possible offset for effect). On mouseoff the above effect would reverse and you would be left with only the first piece of text.

I hope that makes sense, i have been trawling transition and hover over effects on the web, but I can't quite find what I have envisioned.

Comment: You can try to do this with CSS transitions, also.

Comment: Also, this article could help you. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/06/creative-link-effects/

Comment: Those are some cool features, already added to favorites, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little something I knocked together for you as an example. It uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

**The HTML**:

```
<div class="text">
    <a>Text One</a>
    <a>Text Two</a>
</div>
```

**The CSS**:

```
.text{
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
}

.text > a{

    position:relative;
    left:-100%;
    display:none;

}

.text > a:first-child{

  left:0;
  display:block;

}
```

**The JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // here we're only running the code when the page is ready

    $('.text > a:first-child').hover(function(){ // here we're targeting the first .text element

      $(this).siblings().css('display', 'block'); // we're making it visible
      $(this).siblings().animate({'left':'0%'}); // we're animating it out of it's hidden state

    }, function(){ // this function is passed as the second argument to the 'hover' method

      $(this).siblings().animate({'left':'-100%'}, 500, function(){ // animate back to hidden state

        $(this).css('display', 'none'); // when the animation is complete, hide it completely

    });
  });
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cBuWh/) on jsFiddle.

Obviously the concept could be optimised/developed...

Comment: Nope, that's perfect, it's exactly what i had in mind. Thankyou very much

Comment: Hi Shenan, your code looks like what i am after, though i am having issues trying to call the javascript into the html.

I have <script src="hoverover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
in the body of my html, but it seems to make no difference (hoverover is what i called your javascript)

Comment: @JJmason First, note that you need the jQuery library to run this. jQuery is a very helpful library for traversing the DOM and performing CSS changes. You can either go to the [jQuery](www.jquery.com) website and download it, or you can use the Google-hosted version [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) - just include the `<script>` tag in your `<head>`. After that, check that `hover.js` is actually being loaded. Do this with the developer tools of your browser (most browsers have them). You can check any other possible errors with the development console too.

Comment: @JJmason I've adjusted the code a little. I've put comments in the JavaScript so that you can see exactly what is happening on each line. I've also wrapped the whole thing up with a jQuery `ready` method, which means the script only runs once all the HTML elements are ready. This also means you can take your `<script src='hoverover.js></script>` out of the `<body>` (as is best practise) and put it inside the `<head>` of the document.

Comment: Thanks for the Shennan, i have added jquery to the html doc, but alas nothing has changed. However on inspection of the code i do receive this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @JJmason That means jQuery hasn't loaded. Make sure you include the script tag for loading jQuery as per my first comment. Also, use the updated code in my answer.

Comment: @JJmason if the page you're working on is online then  link to the page would help me identify the problem.

Comment: sorry the page isn't online yet, i also have a strange issue where if i link the script src as the google-hosted one, it takes a long time to load and the error given is: Failed to load resource, however i don't receive that error with the jquery.js file i downloaded.

Does that help at all?

Comment: @JJmason Not sure what the issue is then. If the jQuery file that is hosted locally is loaded successfully then you shouldn't have a problem. Make sure you put the jQuery script tags before the `hoverover.js` script tags. the `$` is a jQuery reference, so any reference to it needs to have loaded jQuery first.

Comment: I just have 2 more questions, sorry to be such a bother. Which part of the code controls where "text two" originates from, and how do i make it so i can use "text two" as a clickable link (it disappears currently)?

Comment: @JJmason You could add some options to the anchor tag. So `<a href="the-page-i-want-to-link-to.html">Text Two</a>`. Or you could use jQuery to call some other functionality: `$('a').eq(1).click(function(){ // some code });`. But really you should be learning these basics elsewhere. Go and learn about HTML, CSS, and how you can use JavaScript + jQuery to manipulate both at runtime.